# Cubic root of a complex number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm wondering if there is a mistake in book:
the aim is to find a cubic root of $27$, but both $w_1$ and $w_2$ aren't looking valid

[image: scanavi]

The wrong numbers are $\cos((2\pi)/3)$ and $\sin((2\pi)/3)$ is that right or it's my fault?

I suspect $\cos((2 \pi) / 3)$ must be equal to $-1/2$ and $\sin((2\pi)/3)$ to $-\sqrt3/2$.

The same mistake where it's equal to $4\pi$.

Comment: Cor blimey, they wrote the other two roots in a garden path!

Comment: Well, what *is* the value of $\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}$? -- More problematic with the line line $w_k=\sqrt[3]{27}=\ldots$ is that $\sqrt[3]{27}$ is a real number and the right hand side is not.

Comment: Mathematics is going to be redefined ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root $w_0=3$ is correct, but the other two are wrong. They should be 
$$w_1=3(\cos(2\pi/3)+i\sin(2\pi/3))=\frac{3}{2}(-1+i\sqrt{3})$$
and
$$w_2=3(\cos(4\pi/3)+i\sin(4\pi/3))=\frac{3}{2}(-1-i\sqrt{3}).$$
You can verify them by checking  that $w_1^3=w_2^3=27$:
$$w_1^3=\frac{27}{8}(-1+i\sqrt{3})^3=\frac{27}{8}((-1)^3+
3i\sqrt{3}-3(i\sqrt{3})^2+(i\sqrt{3})^3 )\\
=\frac{27}{8}(-1+
3i\sqrt{3}+9-i3\sqrt{3}) )=27.$$
It's similar for the other one.

Comment: yes, thanks exactly like that.

Comment: @Dmitrii OK. May I know from which book comes this example?

Comment: Sure, http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/8669872/ It's elementary math by Scanavi. It's not international and written in russian but considered to be good and has a lot of positive reviews.

Answer (score 0):

or alternatively $$x^3-27=0$$ is equivalent to $$(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)=0$$

Comment: Apply zero product rule thereafter Followed by the procedure to get roots of a quadratic equation